# Windows Process affinity

Tags: windows, api

I am looking for a way to determine if different threads in a given process run on different cores. I am trying to figure out if they are running truly parallel.

`GetProcessAffinityMask` tells me what the process is allowed to do, but it does not tell me how two concrete running threads are running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the results of [`GetCurrentProcessorNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683181(v=vs.85).aspx) executed on different threads.

MSDN description:

> Retrieves the number of the processor the current thread was running
>   on during the call to this function.

Comment: But worth bearing in mind that coordinating two threads to call this method at "exactly" the same time is challenging, and just because you end up seeing two numbers that are equal, it doesn't mean that the threads are incapable of using other processors, nor in fact that one of them may already have moved over to another one.

Comment: So a thread can jump betwen processors. I didn't consider that. This basically means my question becomes meaningless.